# Swift – Add subview to View Controller from AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am trying to add subview from `AppDelegate` on the currently showing `UIViewController` and I noticed that if that `UIViewController` is displaying an Alert message when `AppDelegate` adds the subview, the subview is added on the `UIAlertController` instead of the `UIViewController`. What will be the best way to display the subview on `UIViewController` instead of any other subviews that the current `UIViewController` might be displaying? Here is my current code.

```
@objc func showStudentLeftTheTestAlert(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
        if let visibleVc = self.window?.visibleViewController {
            // do some other stuff here 
            visibleVc.view.addSubview(StudentLeftTestAlertViewController.sharedInstance.view)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You may add Var vc ： uiviewcontroller? in you delegate. In the view load of your vc : add Uiapplication.shared.delegate.vc = self.  Later you can refer this view controller in your delegate.

Comment: I kinda do not like this solution because I need to go over each of my UIViewControllers and add that line. I was hoping there might be a better way of doing this without modifying each of the view controllers.

Comment: It seems like the above comment is the most suitable solution for my particular project. Thanks E.Coms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the alert message, in fact, is a `UIViewController` presented modally on at your original `UIViewController`. If you want to reach the top `shown` view controller (not `presented`), you may add this method to you `AppDelegate`. It will return you root view controller or the top view controller if you're using a navigation stack.

```
func getTopViewController() -> UIViewController? {
    let rootViewController = self.window?.rootViewController

    if let navigationController = rootViewController as? UINavigationController {
        // get the top view controller from stack if needed
        return navigationController.topViewController
    } else {
        return rootViewController
    }
}
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: Yury Unfortunately I am not using proper navigationController stack for my views so your solution is not suitable for my needs. I will say however that your answer will be very much usable for a lot of people out there and I will mark it as the accepted answer for that reason. Thanks.

Comment: My answer should works even if you're not using `UINavigationController`. Your `AppDelegate.window` always has a `rootViewController` that you can access. What makes you think that the code above is not suitable for your needs?

Comment: Yury how can that be true? My initial view does have UINavigationController but I display all the other views by using self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil). When I call your function, it always returns the top view controller of the navigationStack, which is always my initial view. That is why I said this will be suitable for other scenarios but not for mine.

Comment: @Saik Oh, so the `UIViewController` that is presented under the `AlertViewController` is also `modal`? From your question I thought that it was presented with `push`. So, you have a few modal view controller and want to reach the penultimate one?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to currently showing UIViewController you can add this extension:

```
// MARK: UIApplication extension
extension UIApplication {
    // Get top view controller
    static var topViewController:UIViewController? {
        get{
            if var topController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController {
                while let presentedViewController = topController.presentedViewController {
                    topController = presentedViewController
                }
                return topController
            }else{
                return nil
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

and for use is some like that:

```
guard let vc = UIApplication.topViewController else { return }
```

Where vc is your top controller, can be UINavigationController, UITabbarcontroller or your custom controller, all depend of your navigation flow.